# edit toolbars in AW Blog extension

Tags: extensions

By default, the AW blog extension shows a toolbar/sort bar at the top and bottom of the main blog page.

I want to remove this, and have tried editing the aw_blog.xml deleting the following lines for example:

```
<block type="blog/product_toolbar" name="aw_blog_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
```

... wherever it shows up. However, doing that kills the page and it doesn't load anymore.

So - does anyone know how to remove the toolbar from this extension?

(*obviously, this is a little niche/specfic - but I think many folks know this extension, so maybe i'll get lucky!)*

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its very easy to do this Goto

```
app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/aw_blog
```

open `blog.phtml` file find for this code will be in line `7` and `33` just comment it

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('aw_blog_comments_toolbar'); ?>
```

Comment: ha ha ha... I can't stop laughing... lol..

Comment: @RajeevKTomy bro ?

Comment: @dh47  anyway to chat with you ? skype or google+ or whatever no issue.. :)

Comment: Sure but in the evening's I will message you with my FB profile nut before that please tell me what's wrong in my approach ?

Comment: It is not correct to tell you that here through comments... it is inappropriate.. I want to share a serious stuff to you. fb is not acceptable brother.

Comment: @dh47 please come to this room : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27084/programmerkrt-dh47

Comment: @RajeevKTomy Still waiting for you to listen reason for your laugh

Comment: @dh47 you didnt come to the room !!

Comment: When I'm in you didn't